# To opt out from the long-term-care payroll tax in WA, does the LTC insurance have to be active by Nov 1, 2021, or simply be purchased by Nov 1, 2021?

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, payroll-taxes, washington

To be allowed to opt out from the long-term-care payroll tax in Washington state, does the long-term care insurance have to be active by November 1, 2021, or simply be purchased by November 1, 2021? If the latter, what counts as the purchase date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be allowed to opt out from the long-term-care payroll tax in Washington state, the long-term care insurance has to be *purchased* by November 1, 2021, as stated on https://secureaccess.wa.gov/esd/pfml/EmployeeExemption/Exemption/Forms/Attestation (need to be signed in):

[image]

> Have long-term care insurance as defined in [RCW 48.83.020](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=48.83.020) that was **purchased before November 1, 2021**.

I was told by an insurance broker from Washington that the 1st payment counts as the purchase date.