# What are the minimum financial benefits a long-term care insurance must have to allow a Washington tax resident to opt out from the long-term care tax

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, payroll-taxes, washington

[Revised Code of Washington (RCW) 48.83.020](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=48.83&full=true#48.83.020) ([mirror](https://archive.ph/6cCfS)) states:

> "Long-term care insurance" means an insurance policy, contract, or rider that is advertised, marketed, offered, or designed to provide coverage for at least twelve consecutive months for a covered person.

However, I cannot find any information regarding the minimum financial benefits that this coverage must entail, aside from lasting it least 12 months. E.g., would 1¢USD/day suffice? I'm guessing not, but what is the minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Applying for an exemption](https://wacaresfund.wa.gov/private-insurance/) links to [What qualifies as long-term care insurance?](https://www.insurance.wa.gov/what-qualifies-long-term-care-insurance)

That linked page describes LTC, but does not offer a minimum benefit required.

You were also required to buy the plan [before November 1, 2021](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/145821/5656). FYI